# implementation of round up function in c

Tags: c

Guys this is the function to implement ceil function Which is working fine,I want to ask what is the logic behind subtracting -1 from denominator ?
I am new to programming 
please Help

```
int checkceil(int numerator,int denominator){

    return (numerator+denominator-1)/denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dividing two integers `a` and `b` will always `floor` (truncate) the result, we need to find some `d` (delta) such that `floor(d + a/b) == ceil (a/b)`.

How do we find `d`? Think about it this way:
`ceil(a/b) > floor(a/b)`, except when `(a/b)` is a whole number. So, we want to bump `(a/b)` to (or past) the next whole number, unless `(a/b)` is a whole number, by adding `d`. This way `floor(a/b + d)` will be equal to `ceil(a/b)`. We want to find `d` so that for whole numbers, it won’t quite push them up to the next whole number, but for non-whole numbers it will.

So how much `d` is just enough?

So assuming `(a/b)` is not a whole number, the smallest leftover we can have is `(1/b)`. So in order to bump `(a/b)` to the next whole number, it suffices to add `d = 1 - (1/b)`. This is less than 1, which will not bump `(a/b)` to the next whole number in case `(a/b)` is a whole number, but still enough to bump `(a/b)` to the next whole number in case `(a/b)` is not a whole number.

Summing it up, we know adding `d = 1 - (1/b)` to `(a/b)` will fulfill the equality:
`floor(a/b + d) = ceil(a/b)`. Thus we get:

```
 ceil(a/b) = floor(a/b + d)  = floor(a/b + 1 - 1/b) = floor((a + b - 1)/b)
```

When we write in terms of code it will be:

```
int myceil = (a + b - 1)/b;
```

Answer (score 2):

The numerator *n* is of form `n = a * d + b`, where *b* is the remainder of n / d. The remainder is by definition smaller than *d*.

In C, the division of n/d returns the integral part of *a*. When *b* == 0, one can add only *d - 1* to *n* to get the same result (a*d + 0)/d == (a*d + d-1)/d. For all other remainders `0<b<d`, the division returns the next integer a+1, ie the ceiling.