# How to implement round function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, rounding

There are many answers posted but can't understand how exactly the `round` function in Python works.

- [implementation of round up function in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676314/implementation-of-round-up-function-in-c)
- [How to make a rounding function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65700137/how-to-make-a-rounding-function-in-python)
- [How does Rounding in Python work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620633/how-does-rounding-in-python-work)
- [Python Rounding Inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258464/python-rounding-inconsistently)
- [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior)

There are various ways we can round numbers :

```
 1. Round up
 2. Round down
 3. Round half up
 4. Round half down
 5. Round half away from zero
 6. Round half even (Bankers rounding)
```

I can understand and implement all the rounding techniques except the **6. Round half even** technique.

`Round half even` will round in case of a tie (when we have exactly `0.5` after the rounding digit) and will round the number to the *nearest even number*. So, `round(14.5)` will round it to `14` because `14.5` is between `14` and `15` but `14` is the closest even number. But `round(15.5)` will give `16` because `16` is the closed-even number.

But this becomes very difficult to understand for other cases like `round(7.895, 2)`, `round(7.815, 2)`, `round(7.855, 2)`, `round(7.85, 1)`, `round(7.35, 1)` & `round(7.25, 1)`. I can't understand now how rounding works they give very strange values which is difficult to understand.

Here are implementations of different rounding methods except for `round half to even` that I want to understand how to implement:

**1. Round up**

```
def round_up(num, place=0):
    power = 10 ** place
    return math.ceil(num * power) / power
```

**2. Round Down**

```
def round_down(num, place=0):
    power = 10 ** place
    return math.floor(num * power ) / power
```

**3. Round half up**

```
def round_half_up(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return math.floor(n * multiplier + 0.5) / multiplier
```

**4. Round half down**

```
def round_half_down(n, decimals=0):
    power = 10 ** decimals
    return math.floor(n * power + 0.4) / power
```

**5. Round half away from zero**

```
def round_half_away_from_zero(num, decimals=0):
    power = 10 ** decimals
    return math.copysign(math.floor(abs(num) * power + 0.5) / power, num)
```

**6. Round half even (Bankers rounding)**

How to implement the round half-even method?

Comment: What's your exact problem? "strange" is totally subjective and unclear.  [ask] and [mre]

Comment: @Julien, I want to know how to implement the round function that is in Python and also explain how The Bankers rounding algorithm works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3.x rounding behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825926/python-3-x-rounding-behavior) Tl;Dr You don't need to implement anything Python's builtin `round` function has the behaviour you want.

Comment: @Udesh You have already explained how Bankers Rounding works

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat but there is no concrete implementation for the round function.

Comment: @CtrlZ but I doubt that what I know is limited because there are some cases that I couldn't understand, and I have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: Regarding your other cases, you simply should forget worrying how rounding works in them since that goes into floating point territory where the math is more approximate (0.5 is also floating point but 0.5 can exactly be represented being a negative power of 2). About "_but there is no concrete implementation for the round function_" there **is** in the implementation of the builtin `round` function.

Comment: From Java documentation: *Rounding mode to round towards the "nearest neighbor" unless both neighbors are equidistant, in which case, round towards the even neighbor. Behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_UP if the digit to the left of the discarded fraction is odd; behaves as for RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN if it's even.* What's troubling you?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès this discussion is regarding Python's round function, and I wanted to implement the round function that is in Python to better understand more about it.

Answer (score 0):

The term is mentioned as `bankers rounding method` because the scenario where bankers need rounding is - when they want to skip the lower money unit.
For example: Let us take an example of different countries' money units.

Say if they want to round off :
dollars and cents    round off to    only dollars   (or)
pounds and pence     round off to    only pounds
Euros and cents      round off to    only Euros
Dhirams and fils     round off to    only Dhirams
Rupees and paise     round off to    only rupees

So if the decimal potion is exactly .50 It'll convert to the nearest even. Even if it is 0.51, the rounding method is normal method

```
print(round(2.5))
#output: 2. Because 2 is the even number. If rounded off to 3, 3 is odd

print(round(6.50))
#outout 6. Because 7 is an odd number

print(round(7.5))
#output 8. Because 7 is an odd  number

print(round(6.51))
#output : 7. Because 6.51 is more than 6.5
```

It will round of the nearest even number - only if the decimal is 0.5 or 0.50 or 0.500 etc., Also it is applicable for the numbers found before decimal. And appilcable for each decimals. For eg.,

```
print(round(7.525, 2))
output: 7.53
```

in the above example , the output is 7.53 and not 7.54. Because Here the rounding off is in decimal level. So the traditional method of rounding is used (i.e) if the next decimal is more than 5.

Edit for more explanation:
The above idea is absolutely correct in case of `round(number, 0)` or simply `round(number)`. (i.e) if no number to be mentioned after decimal point.

In dealing with decimal:
While dealing with decimal python follows IEEE 754 standard for floating-point. That is it takes accurate value in binary. In case of numbers after decimal point, the accurate value is slightly difficult. IEEE 754 takes higher end if the accurate binary value is closer to the next digit. Takes lower number if the accurate
binary value is slightly closer to lower number

```
print(round(7.525, 2)) # Output :7.53


print(round(7.895,2)) # output : 7.90
```

Comment: In that case `round(7.895, 2)` should return `7.9` but its returned `7.89`

Comment: @Udesh you have to understand you are dealing with floating point numbers, and that [floating point math is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). If you run `7.8949999999999996 == 7.895` you get the result as `True`, justifying the output you get.